# Upgrade hardware enablement stack but retain kernel

Tags: 14.04, kernel, xorg, security, hardware-enablement-stack

Ubuntu 14.04.01

According to official documentation, upgrading the hardware enablement stack in Ubuntu to utopic-lts upgrades the kernel and xorg. I only want to upgrade xorg to correct a display problem. The problem is the utopic-lts stack is only supported for 9 months after which I would have to upgrade the HWE stack again.

The question is: is it safe from a security standpoint on a conventional desktop system, to roll back the kernel to the 3.13 series with security updates until 2019 and hold xorg at the utopic-lts for that same duration ie without upgrading the HWE stack every 6-9 months?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to update the x-org display drivers, why not look into installing the [oibaf PPA](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers) or [xorg edgers PPA](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).  I know for sure the oibaf ppa doesn't work with the hardware enablement stack it is meant to work with your existing kernel and just update the x-org video drivers.

I use oibaf with 14.04. Just add the PPA in **Software and Updates**  or run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

then, in either case, do:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

followed by:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```